# Can I configure specific objects with Guice like I can with Spring's XML?

Tags: guice

I have an existing library I'm trying to integrate into an application that uses Guise for DI. I'm new to Guice, but I have some experience with XML-configured Spring. I'm trying to figure out how to do something with Guice that I know how to do with Spring.

In a different spring-configured app I have a chunk of config XML that looks like this:

```
<!-- consumer 1 -->
<bean id="someJMSMessageConsumer" class="com.foo.jms.Consumer">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="settings" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="com.foo.bar.SomeJMSMessageHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="MyClientId" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="SOME.JMS.MESSAGE" />
    <constructor-arg index="4" value="false" />
    <constructor-arg index="5" ref="signatureService"/>
</bean>

<!-- consumer 2 -->
<bean id="anotherJMSMessageConsumer" class="com.foo.jms.Consumer">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="settings" />
    <constructor-arg index="1">
        <bean class="com.foo.bar.AnotherJMSMessageHandler" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2" value="MyClientId" />
    <constructor-arg index="3" value="ANOTHER.JMS.MESSAGE" />
    <constructor-arg index="4" value="false" />
    <constructor-arg index="5" ref="signatureService"/>
</bean>
```

Note that both of these beans are instances of com.foo.jms.Consumer, just configured differently. Both of these objects are instantiated immediately (not Lazy) and hang around and wait for something to happen.

So, how can I tell Guice to instantiate these two different instances and inject their different dependencies. I figure I'd do this in the configure() method, but I don't know *how*.

Another important point is that the com.foo.jms.Consumer is part of the existing library I'm implementing. While I can edit this library, I'd rather not so as to avoid breaking any other applications that use it.

It's also important to note that the com.foo.bar.whatever object *are* part of my application. The all implement an interface provided by the same existing library that com.foo.jms.Consumer comes from. Basically, I have several Consumers configured to listen for different messages and call a function on a specific implementation of an interface.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Some more reading suggests that PrivateModule might be the best solution. However, it looks like I'll have to write one PrivateModule class per com.foo.jms.Consumer object I need to configure. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for [Binding Annotations](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations)!

In your module you can use it like this:

```java
@Named("someJMSMessageConsumer)
@Provides
Consumer getSomeJMSMessageConsumer(SomeJMSMessageHandler handler) {
    // handler has been automagically injected by Guice
    return new Customer(handler);
}
```

As you can see, if you need other dependencies injected for the call to `Customer`'s constructor, just add them as a parameter to the `getSomeJMSMessageConsumer` method - Guice will inject them.

Do this for the other instance (this time annotating the `@Provides` method with `@Named(anotherJMSMessageConsumer)`, of course), changing the parameters, etc. as needed.

Now you can inject the selected instance like this:

```java
@Inject
public SomeClass(@Named("someJMSMessageConsumer") Customer customer) {
}
```

Instead of `Named` you can create your own custom annotation. Instead of a `@Provides` method, you can use a `Provider`. The examples are in the Guice's documentation linked above.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I've actually decided not to use the application that was requiring me to use Guice, so I'm not going to test/confim with code that this is correct. However, it makes total sense and I'll accept it. Add on question: Can I somehow configure Guice to non-lazily load the  someJMSMessageConsumer as a singleton when the application loads? It's not intended to be wired into anything, but still needs to be instantiated.

Comment: Non-lazily means... eagerly :) Guice has just the thing: [eager singletons](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Scopes#eager-singletons)